# How to set value of composited fields in grails constructor?

Tags: grails

Say I have an enum in my superclass..

```
enum SomeEnum{
    //some enums here.
}
```

Then in my parent class, I have:

```
class myParentClass {
    SomeEnum someEnum
}
```

Then my child class:

```
class myChildClass {
MyParentClass myParentClass

myChildClass(){
   //what to place here?
   //I expect.. super.someEnum = SomeEnum.ENUM_HERE but i didnt extend it.. so?
   //  I tried this.someEnum = SomeEnum.ENUM_HERE but it didn't work either... :(
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have a composition relationship and not inheritance. If you want `myChildClass` to be a child of `myParentClass` then define your child like this

```
class myChildClass extends myParentClass{
}
```

and then you can instantiate your child object like this

```
def child = new myChildClass(someEnum : ENUM_VALUE)
```

Any properties defined in the parent will be inherited to the child. No need to define a constructor in your child class. All Grails domains come with dynamic Map constructors that allow you to pass the properties as a map when instantiating new instances.